# how to convert mongodb Decimal128 to json in rust

Tags: json, mongodb, rust

i got some data in mongodb like this

```
[{"versions": {"version1": {"app": Decimal128(1.1)}}}]
```

i want to convert it to json string in rust,but output like this.

```
[{"versions": {"version1": {"app": "$numberDecimalBytes": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62, 48]}}}]
```

how to convert `$numberDecimalBytes` to a string or float in json output?

this is my code.

```
pub fn get_all_versions(db_name: String) -> Result<Json<Vec<Document>>, Status> {
    let db = MongoCLient::init(db_name);
    let version = db.get_all_version();
    let val = version.unwrap();
    Ok(Json(val))
}

pub fn get_all_version(&self) -> Result<Vec<Document>, Error> {
    let cursors = self
        .version_model
        .find(None, None)
        .ok()
        .expect("Error getting list of users");
    let versions = cursors.map(|doc| doc.unwrap()).collect();
    Ok(versions)
}
```

i try to used `Decimal128.to_string()` to convert a float string, but just output "Decimal128(...)"

Comment: To attract answers you should probably provide a [mre] including all the types you use (the `use` statement or their definiton for local types). Without it it's hard or even impossible to provide accurate answers since there is a lot of guesswork involved. You should also copy & paste said mre here to avoid typos like `MongoCLient`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.